# Как декодировать URL, чтобы часть символов была в Lowercase?

Tags: java, url, java-8

Есть encoded URL. После декодирования

```
String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(encodedLink, "UTF-8");        
String delims = "[u, &]";
String[] splittedURL = decodedURL.split(delims);
String resultURL = splittedURL[1].substring(1);
```

получаю следующий урл:

```
http://example.com?I=vNjWAwAAAABfva85AgAAAABR%2Fv%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FBGNhdnMA%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8%3D
```

Но в этой части:

```
%2Fv%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FBGNhdnMA%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8%3D
```

мне необходимо, чтобы "F" и "D" буквы были в Lowercase:
(F -> f,
D -> d).
Возможно ли выполнить это посредством декодирования без сплита урла с последующей заменой заглавных букв на строчные посредством:

```
.toLowerCase();
```

?

Comment: Great! But I need to practice in English)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Спасибо, Михаил) Done!

Comment: а зачем вам это нужно? в стандарте рекомендовано использовать БОЛЬШИЕ буквы.

Comment: Мне нужно сравнить в автотесте исходный урл и этот, декодированный урл. В исходном урле буквы f - строчные. Тест падает.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте для сравнения функцию `string equalsIgnoreCase(anotherString)`.

Comment: Не совсем то, что надо, т.к. линки сравниваются компоратором.